# Resize image automatically on screen resize

Tags: css

I want to make an navigation using icons. I want these icons to get smaller as the screen size gets smaller. Currently, I'm having this:

http://jsbin.com/yesitepuwo/edit?html,css,output
[it's possible that the link does not work in firefox?]

As you see, the images first collapse, so the second is below the first one. If you further resize the window, so it gets even smaller, you can see that the images resize nicely.

The problem is: I don't want them to collapse but only to resize. So how do I do that?

Another html mark-up is totally fine. But please not, that on the smallers collapse point I'd like to display a burger menu and make an android like, tiled menu istead of the icons being strung beneath each other. It would be nice if your solution also respects that. [That's where the automatically collapsing is nice, maybe one can set min-width to the images so they collapse again?]

Thanks :)

Comment: You need to specify a width in a percentage on the `li` items or the images will not shrink, as they always want to be their inherit width until the viewport changes. You can also look into using `flexbox` for the menu. The second part of your question is asking the community to write markup for you. What have you tried in regards to the burger menu?

Comment: I did not intend to ask for markup, I only wanted to tell you were this is going so you might suggest solutions which won't get in conflict with that future plans - that's all. Sorry for confusion. I did not really try a lot when it comes to the burger menu. I actually was using bootstrap but I kind of switched to "doing it myself". But yeah, maybe I should actually start coding it from the mobile view first - but I think the question remains anyway. About flexbox: it seems to be rather new, I'd prefere most basic css code. :) For backwards compability. Thanks for the hint on the li

Comment: it actually works with a set width but I'd prefere to not set one. :/ otherwise I'd have to use inline css which does set widthon html generation... also this is bound to the screen size in general - I'd like to only let them resize if they don't have any space left :/

Comment: No worries! Flexbox isn't really new and is supported by most browsers (including IE10). http://caniuse.com/#search=flex and would also solve your second comment of not knowing the width because of dynamic generation.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
ul{
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
ul:after {content:'';display:block;clear:both;}
li{
  display:block;
  float:left;
  max-width: 50%;
}
img {
  width:100%;
}
@media (max-width:300px) {
  li {max-width:100%;}
}
```

or if you wand to have it as inline-blocks:

```
ul{
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
li{
  display:inline-block;
  max-width: 50%;
}
img {
  width:100%;
}
@media (max-width:300px) {
  li {max-width:100%;}
}
```

but then you have to remove all spaces between your li elements, because inline-block are treated as words so browser displays spaces between them (50% + space + 50% > 100%).

Comment: thanks - I'll look at it but isnt there a solution widhout specific widths?

Comment: actually this is also not exactly what I wanted. See http://jsbin.com/siheqesuse/1/edit?html,css,output  when you resize the window, everything gets resized. I only want the images to resize, if there is no space left on their left and their right. If they get squeezed by the screen.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand completely. What do you mean by everything gets resized? Is there something except images?Do you want the to collapse at all? I understand that you don't know the size of your images beforehand, is that correct?

Comment: Nevermind :) I've got 2 examples which exactly do what I want. See answer above. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

So, here are two approaches which work as I wanted it to work:

https://jsbin.com/nexatoxewi/edit?html,css,output

https://jsbin.com/pibavejedo/edit?html,css,output